# Stuck on a linked list multiple class implementation

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I have been working on this project for several days. This project contains 3 classes. The first is a DNA class that stores a DNA object. The second is a database class that reads a file and parses commands and data and deals with it accordingly. The last is a DNA list class that is a linked list of nodes that have pointers to DNA objects.

I've completed my linked list building method. It is required to be a push_back method that adds nodes at the end of the list. My problem arises when I try to search the list for a certain node. This has to be a method that returns a DNA* if a DNA object with id exists in the list; otherwise it returns NULL.

My plan is to use this method to print and also delete the node. I can't seem to get this method to work. Obviously I'm a little shaky with pointers. It took me several hours to implement my push_back method. Here is my code. Any guidance or help is appreciated.

DNA.h

```
#ifndef DNA_H
#define DNA_H

#include <string>

class DNA{  
public:
   // overloaded constructor for DNA class
   DNA(std::string, int, std::string, int, int);
   // print function
   void print();
   int getID();

private:
   std::string m_label;      // variable to hold label
   int m_id;                    // variable to hold id
   std::string m_sequence;  // variable to hold sequence
   int m_length;                // variable to hold length
   int m_index;             // variable to hold index
};
#endif
```

DNA implementation

```
#include "DNA.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

DNA::DNA(string label, int id, string sequence, int length, int index){
    m_label = label;
    m_id = id;
    m_sequence = sequence;
    m_length = length;
    m_index = index;
}

void DNA::print(){
     cout << "DNA:" << '\t' << "label: " << m_label << '\t' << "ID: " << m_id << '\t' << "Sequence: " << m_sequence << endl << "Length: " << m_length << '\t' << "cDNAStartIndex: " << m_index << endl << endl;
}

int DNA::getID(){
    return m_id;
}
```

Database class

```
#ifndef SEQUENCEDATABASE_H
#define SEQUENCEDATABASE_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "DNA.h"
#include "DNAList.h"

class SequenceDatabase {
public:
    SequenceDatabase();
    // function to import the data file, parse the data, and perform the required output
    void importEntries(std::string);
private:
    DNAList list;

};
#endif
```

Database implemenation

```
#include "SequenceDatabase.h"
#include "DNA.h"
#include "DNAList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

SequenceDatabase::SequenceDatabase(){

    DNAList list;
}
// function reads in the filename creates a data stream and performs the requested actions
void SequenceDatabase::importEntries(string inputFile){
    ifstream dnaFile(inputFile);
    char command;
    string label, sequence;
    int id, length, index;
    while(dnaFile >> command){
        DNA* p;
        if(command == 'D'){
            dnaFile >> label >> id >> sequence >> length >> index;
            DNA data(label, id, sequence, length, index);
            p = new DNA(label, id, sequence, length, index);
            list.push_back(p);
        }
        if(command == 'P'){
        dnaFile >> id;
        cout << "Printing " << id << " ..." << endl << endl;
        p = list.findId(id);
        if(p == nullptr)
            cout << "Can not find item " << "(" << id << ")!" << endl << endl;
        else
        p-> print();
        }
    }
    dnaFile.close();
}
```

Finally my list class

```
#ifndef DNALIST_H
#define DNALIST_H

#include "DNA.h"
#include "sequenceDatabase.h"

struct DNANode{
    DNA* data;
    DNANode* next;
    DNANode* prev;
};


class DNAList{
public:
    DNAList();
    DNAList(DNA* newDNA);
    void push_back(DNA* newDNA);
    DNA* findId(int);
    void obliterate(int id);
    int size();

private:
    DNANode* head;
    int list_size;

};
#endif
```

List implementation

```
#include "DNA.h"
#include "sequenceDatabase.h"
#include "DNAList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DNAList::DNAList(){
    head = new DNANode;
    head->next = nullptr;
    list_size = 0;

}

DNA* DNAList::findId(int id){    // this function is my problem
    DNANode* current;
    current = head;
    while(current->next != nullptr){
        if(current->data->getID() == id){
            return current->data;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int DNAList::size(){
    return list_size;

}

void DNAList::push_back(DNA* newDNA){
    DNANode* current;
    DNANode* last;
    DNANode* p;
    p = new DNANode;
    p->data = newDNA;
    last = nullptr;
    current = head;
    cout << "Adding " << newDNA->getID() << " ..." << endl << endl;
    while(current != nullptr){
        last = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if(current == head->next){
        p->next = nullptr;
        p->prev = head;
        head->next = p;
    }
    else{
        p->next = current;
        p->prev = last;
        last->next = p;
    }
    list_size++;
}
```

I wasn't sure if I should post the whole code, but i felt it was needed to understand the problem. My problem arises when i try to call the find function to print the data in the node.

Comment: From perusing the code, it looks like your findId method will indeed return the DNA object corresponding to the id. Is it the deleting part you are unclear on? You might want to read 'Data Structures and Algorithms' by Aho et al. That has everything you need to know about linked lists.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are facing with your program?

Comment: You may want to use `std::list` rather than creating your own.

Comment: Is this a real project or a school project with artificial restrictions eg no `std::list` and `std::find`?

Comment: @NeilKirk You mean `std::list::find`?

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line, in which file, is causing issues?

Comment: Also this is a school project with restrictions.

Comment: @kemotoe Remove `->next` in `while (current->next != nullptr)`. It will break when `current == nullptr`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I made the change.I used the debugger to step into the function. It receives the right id. After the line current = head. I don't think it is receiving the data from my list. Under locals current m_id = ???

Comment: I looked at this because of the linked-list tag, but I'm more of a C guy than a C++ one. However, the lines `DNA *p` followed by `p = new DNA...` look suspect to me. Can't you just pass the `new DNA(...)` directly to your push_back method?

Comment: Yes I could, but my push_back method is working fine.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `head` member variable of `DNAList` is initialized with `new DNANode`. Since `DNANode` doesn't have an explicit constructor, its compiler generated one will not initialize the pointers `data`, `next` and `prev`. `next` is initialized on the next line, but `data` is left as a garbage value.

Inside `findId`, this line is executed:

```
if (current->data->getID() == id){
```

However the first time around the loop, `current` is pointing `head`. This means you are trying to look at the garbage value, which will possibly crash.

One solution is to change the `findId` function to start at `head->next`, another is to initialise the `data` pointer in `head` to `nullptr` and check that `data` is not `nullptr` before you access it.

A better solution might be to just have `head` as `nullptr` to start with, rather than having a dummy `DNANode` at the top. This would involve changing some of the code in `push_back`, but might make it easier to understand.

Comment: You sir are amazing. This fixed the problem. I assume I would need to do the same thing with an obliterate function?

Comment: If you leave the head as a placeholder, then any function that traverses the list will have to know that the head element should be skipped. If you change head to nullptr, then the functions will need to check for nullptr (which they would do anyway, in their loops).

Answer (score 1):

Aha. I think what is causing the problem is that towards the end of your `SequenceDatabase::importEntries()` method you are setting `if(p=nullptr)` instead of making the comparison `if(p == nullptr)`. This is no doubt causing the error you see. This is a common mistake.

Comment: So another thing that I notice is that you're print method is a member of the class `DNA`, but findID is returning a `DNAnode`, not a `DNA` I think you want p to be a `DNAnode` and then use `p->data->print` instead of `p->print`.

Comment: Also, you should probably not use p at all. Simply pass the desired object by calling your findId method, ie `if(list.findId(id) == nullptr)` and `list.findId(id)->data->print()`.